# How to execute inline query as a pass through query?

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I'm trying to delete records from table and it works when we have local table in MS Access but when I convert it into linked table (via SQL Server) then it will through some error. I have searched everywhere to find a solution for this but I eventually found that I don't get any error if I use this query as a pass-through query.

Now my question is how do I execute this query as a pass-through query without creating it first?

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Set db = CurrentDb
Dim rsRUDelete As DAO.Recordset

Set rsRUDelete = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM table")
If rsRUDelete.AbsolutePosition > -1 Then
    With rsRUDelete
        .MoveFirst
        Do Until .EOF
            .Delete
            .MoveNext
        Loop
    End With
End If
```

Comment: "some error" is not very specific...

Comment: It's a **query** (not *querry* - one "r" in there is quite enough!)

Comment: You need to at least post the actual error.

Answer (score 1):

You simply have to save the query as pass-though. So you can build the query like:

delete from faxbook3

So, if you save the above as a pass-though query named "MyPass"

Then in VBA code, you go:

```
Currentdb.querydefs("MyPass").Execute
```

If you wanted to create the SQL on the fly, or say only delete one record, then once  you have the above pass-though query saved, then you can create pass-though (t-sql) commands on the fly like this:

```
With currentdb.querydefs("MyPass")
   .SQL = "delete from faxBook3 where ID = " & myVBAVairable
   .EXECUTE
End with
```

So there is no need for a recordset, and more worse is any reocrdset created from a pass-though query is read only and thus does not allow edits or deletes of the data.

However there is no need to write all that code and create world poverty since a simple delete query will more then suffice here.